# Hadoop per-file block size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop book it is said that we can specify per-file block size at the time of creation of file.

"The most natural way to increase the split size is to have larger blocks in HDFS, by setting dfs.block.size, or on a per-file basis at file construction time."

Any idea how to do this at file construction time. I hope by setting this to value = file-size, the file will not be split

Comment: Basically I have a streaming Job (c++ code) and I simply copy input files into HDFS using -CoprFromLocal. Is there is any option available here to specify file block-size. I think HDFS provides an api to specify block size when you create a file. FileSystem.create(Path, overwrite, bufferSize, replication, blockSize, progress). But probably I can not use this. I am looking for some cli option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use CLI:

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=file-size -put local_name remote_location
```

or you can use Java API to specify the dfs.block.size when you want to create or copy files.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setInt("dfs.block.size",file-size);
```

Comment: I tried the CLI option. But it seems when the job is launched MapReduce still tries to split the file if it is greater than 64 MB, though I mentioned df.block.size as 256MB while copying the file to HDFS. I was hoping that MR will not split the file with above option.

Comment: you can check the file's block size in 50070. you can **Browse the filesystem** to see whether the file has the correct block size.