# Does HDFS stores non splittable files in one data node?

Tags: java, hadoop, compression, hdfs

For non splittable files such as `GZIP` there will be only one map job because `GZIP` files are no splittable. Is there any option or optimization to store all blocks of such files in one data node so we can at least save network bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing HDFS block size for your gzip file to be larger than file size should do the trick. For more info on setting HDFS block size per file see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171906/hadop-per-file-block-size)